# Swift: JSON is nil when accessing NSDictionairy

Tags: json, swift, alamofire

When I print(JSON) I get the files, so the .request works.
But when I am trying to access the "test" key (which exists) I get nil

I get

> "I am here"
>   "now ,I am here"

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, self.APIBaseUrl , parameters: ["api_key": self.APIkey])
            .responseJSON { response in
                if let JSON = response.result.value {
                  print("I am here")
                  if let str = JSON as? NSDictionary {
                     print("now , I am here")
                     if let movieUrlString = str["poster_path"] as? String)! {
                        print("but now here")
                        }
```

EDITED

```
print(dict)


**dates** =     {
maximum = "2015-10-21";
minimum = "2015-09-30";
};
page = 1;
**results** =     (
            {
 adult = 0;
"poster_path" = "/2XegKZ0I4QrvzpEHneigRk6YTB1.jpg";
```

++(more results)

Comment: Could you be more specific?

Comment: its the TMDB database and the result is :

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use more meaningful debug printing statements and variables names. Also you were not using the right variable for subscripting. Fixed example:

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, self.APIBaseUrl , parameters: ["api_key": self.APIkey]).responseJSON { response in
    if let JSON = response.result.value {
        print("inside JSON result")
        if let dict = JSON as? NSDictionary {
            print("inside decoded JSON")
            if let results = dict["results"] as? [NSDictionary] {
                for result in results {
                    if let movieUrlString = result["poster_path"] as? String {
                        print(movieUrlString)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: yes you are right , I copied the wrong block. I am still getting inside JSON result - 
inside decoded JSON

Comment: And? What is your question? If `if let arrayOfURLs = dict["poster_path"] as? [String]` doesn't work, it means that either the key `dict["poster_path"]` doesn't exist, or it doesn't contain an array of strings. Debug by doing `print(dict)` instead of `print("inside decoded JSON")`.

Comment: print(dict) :  popularity = "4.931529";
            "poster_path" = "/AjbENYG3b8lhYSkdrWwlhVLRPKR.jpg";
            "release_date" = "2015-10-02";
            title = "The Martian";
            video = 0;
            "vote_average" = "6.1";
            "vote_count" = 39;
        },
                {
            adult = 0;
            "backdrop_path" = "/6h0mKpQc252IQOBNlbl5VWBqx0f.jpg";
            "genre_ids" =             (
                53,
                27
            );
            id = 360321;
            "original_language" = en;

Comment: `dict["poster_path"]` is not an array, it's a string: I've updated my answer.

Comment: my mistake , the results are endless . I was trying to point out that the "poster_path" exists. but still String or [String] I cant

Comment: Given what you pasted in the comment, `if let movieUrlString = dict["poster_path"] as? String` should work and should extract `"/AjbENYG3b8lhYSkdrWwlhVLRPKR.jpg"`. If not, then *please add details and context to your question*, mostly print an accurate JSON response snippet.

Comment: Thx Eric , I noticed the error . the dict has first dates =     {
        maximum = "2015-10-21";
        minimum = "2015-09-30";
    };
    page = 1;
    results =     (
                {
            adult = 0;
            "backdrop_path" = "/2XegKZ0I4QrvzpEHneigRk6YTB1.jpg";
           So I need to access the results first.

Comment: Please add details *to your question*, not here in comments. Use the "edit" button. Thank you.